# npm start error this program is blocked by group policy

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I have created one example react application for react-data-grid .I am executing this application using node.js npm command. Initially i was able to run npm start and able to see the grid. Suddenly npm start stopped working . It is giving below error. I am unable to figure it out .
[image]

Comment: I got the solution. It is windows level policy issue .Need to give access to execute npm files in windows policies

Comment: It would be helpful if Explain what steps you followed .